# i want to change the quotes every minute but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the quotes every minute.

here is my code. it gets the time and then saves to the ".time" element every second. the js only show the last quote always and sometimes it takes time to show that quote.

the page will reload every second

```js
window.setInterval("reloadpage()", 1000);
function reloadpage() {
  let date = new Date();
  let ampm;
  let hour;
  let hours = date.getHours();

  //if hours will be more than 12 
  if (hours <= 12) {
    hours = hour;

    ampm = "AM";
  } else {
    hour = hours % 12;
    ampm = "PM";
  }
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date.getSeconds();

  //displaying time


  let time = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + ampm;

  let ctime = document.querySelector(".time");
  ctime.innerHTML = time;
}

//reload quotes in every minute

window.setInterval("reloadquote()", 60000);
  function reloadquote() {
  let quotes = ["hello", "kya hua", "gufufish", "wuwfywoifhw"];

  //I think the problem is here

  for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("Quote").innerHTML = quotes[i];
  }
}
```

```css
/*ignore CSS*/
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#Quote{
  width:100%;
  background:#4cffcf;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px;
  margin:5px;
  font-size:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
<blockquote id="Quote">Quote Placeholder</blockquote>
```

Comment: Need to see html code.

Comment: Please, add more description to the problem. Show more code and add more details.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` - you are always looping over _all_ quotes here, and assign them to the target element in direct succession, so of course you only see the last one at the end. You need to keep a counter variable _outside_ of the scope of your function, and increase it by one every time it gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you always seeing `wuwfywoifhw` in the quote... If so, then here is what's happening...
Every minute `reloadquote` will actually be executing, but the problem is when it runs, it executes setting the `innerHTML` for all the four quotes in the `for` loop and so remains visible is the last one.

Try this instead...

```
 window.setInterval("reloadquote()", 60 * 1000);
 const originalQuotes = ["hello", "kya hua", "gufufish", "wuwfywoifhw"];
 let replayedQuotes = originalQuotes;

 function reloadquote() {
   if (replayedQuotes.length) {
     const nextQuote = replayedQuotes[0];

     document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = nextQuote;

     replayedQuotes = replayedQuotes.slice(1);
   } else {
     replayedQuotes = originalQuotes;
     reloadQuote();
   }
 }
```